# How to scroll element automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a slide show project

http://jsfiddle.net/L73T5/8/

The user can scroll the slides content and when they scroll down, the previous slide contents will be hidden behind the slide images (this part is done)

However, when a user clicks an slide image on top, I want my `slide-content-containter` jump to correspond slide contents.

For example, if a user click `slide2`, I want to see `slide2` contents under my 4 slide images and `slide1` content will be scrolled to top automatically and hidden behind 4 slide images.

I started my script but not sure how to go from there. Can anyone help me out? I really appreciate it!

Comment: Take a look at [jQuery ScrollSpy](http://plugins.jquery.com/scrollSpy/) And look at the [example](https://raw.github.com/thesmart/jquery-scrollspy/master/example/example-1.html) on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

The Ids must be unique! You're using the same ids many times.

Comment: my mistake, please see the jsfiddle agian.

Comment: It's the same old. <a id='slide1'... and <div id='slide1'>

Comment: I updated again, it looks fine to me. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">     </script>
 </script>
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.slide').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            goToByScroll(id);

        })
        function goToByScroll(id) {
            id = id + "Detail";
            var TopPosition = $("#" + id).position().top;
            $("#slide-content-container").animate({ scrollTop: TopPosition });
        }
    });
</script>
<style>
    #slide-list-container
    {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }


    #slide-content-container
    {
        width: 680px;
        height: 865px;
        float: left;
        overflow: auto;
        background-color: white;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id='slide-list-container'>
    <a id='slide1' class='slide' href='#slide1-details'>
        <img src='http://i39.tinypic.com/1zfsnrb.jpg' />
    </a><a id='slide2' class='slide' href='#slide1-details'>
        <img src='http://i39.tinypic.com/1zfsnrb.jpg' />
    </a><a id='slide3' class='slide' href='#slide1-details'>
        <img src='http://i39.tinypic.com/1zfsnrb.jpg' />
    </a><a id='slide4' class='slide' href='#slide1-details'>
        <img src='http://i39.tinypic.com/1zfsnrb.jpg' />
    </a>
</div>
<div id='slide-content-container'>
    <div id='slide1Detail'>
        <h1>
            Slide1</h1>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula
        eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient
        montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu,
        pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla
        vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a,
        venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.
        Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean
        leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante,
        dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius
        laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur
        ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus
        eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque
        sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas
        nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus.
        Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed
        fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo
        eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</div>
    <div id='slide2Detail'>
        <h1>
            Slide2</h1>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula
        eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient
        montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu,
        pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla
        vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a,
        venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.
        Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean
        leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante,
        dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius
        laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur
        ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus
        eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque
        sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas
        nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus.
        Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed
        fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo
        eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</div>
    <div id='slide3Detail'>
        <h1>
            Slide3</h1>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula
        eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient
        montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu,
        pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla
        vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a,
        venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.
        Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean
        leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante,
        dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius
        laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur
        ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus
        eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque
        sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas
        nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus.
        Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed
        fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo
        eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</div>
    <div id='slide4Detail'>
        <h1>
            Slide4</h1>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula
        eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient
        montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu,
        pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla
        vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a,
        venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.
        Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean
        leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante,
        dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius
        laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur
        ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus
        eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque
        sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas
        nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus.
        Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed
        fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo
        eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There was so many Id conflicts in your code, thats why i have changed some of the tags and styles.

Comment: thank you so much. I have updated my jsfiddle with your codes. http://jsfiddle.net/L73T5/9/ It seems the slideDetail div is a bit off after I click the slide image. Also, If I click the same images twice the slideDetail will go off too. I was working on this approach as well. Thanks for the help!

Comment: still trying to figure out how to fix those off position I mentioned in my comments. :)